# Is there any proof of cauchy formula for repeated integration without induction?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, alternative-proof

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration

Here, the formula has been proved by using mathematical induction. Is there any other way to prove it? I mean how did cauchy himself derive it?

Comment: Once you manage to define repeated integration rigorously without recursion, it may be possible to prove it without induction.

Comment: By rigorously, what exactly do you mean? Can you give an example? Also, how did Cauchy arrive at the formula?